# What are the differences between region and prefered location of an Cloud SQL instance?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, gcloud

Editing an instance, we can see two inputs as below snapshot about region and about location.

How would we distinguish the two?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Within a region, there are multiple physical locations your instance can be. By setting your Preferred Location, your instance will come up in the same location as an App Engine or Google Compute Engine instance. This will minimize latency between your Cloud SQL instance and the othe AE/GCE instance.

Additionally, your Cloud SQL instance will follow the instance you've tied it to, so they will both locate next to each other, even if your AE/GCE instance moves.

If you don't care, you can leave Preferred Location to None.

Comment: Please give examples for different locations for a region - is it like Asia region will have east-asia1-a, east-asia1-b, and east-asia1-c?

Comment: GCE is a Google Compute Engine instance.

Comment: Don't worry about different locations within a region, we do that for you :) Preferred Location will make sure we always try and place your Cloud SQL instance where latency is minimized.

Comment: what if the app engine server moves to another region for failover? would the Cloud SQL instance move too? If you failover the Cloud SQL instance to another location, does it move back at some point?